# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, poo

Hola es mi primer pregunta en stackoverflow y no logro encontrar el error.

Estoy tratando de settear un simple texto a un TextView pero me causa errores al usar findViewById, ya probé resetear la cache de android studio , tambien intenté actualizar android studio a la version 2021.2.1 y sigue causando el mismo error.

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

at com.example.huertovertical.Monitoreo1.onCreate(Monitoreo1.java:25)

muchas gracias a todos por la atención.

```
package com.example.huertovertical;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Monitoreo1 extends Activity {
    private TextView temp;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference referenceEntrada1 = database.getReference("LECTURAS");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoreo1);
        temp = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
        temp.setText("Hola mundo");




        referenceEntrada1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                String estadoSensor = snapshot.child("hum").getValue().toString();
//                temp.setText(estadoSensor);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}

//El activity 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECF0F1"
    tools:context=".Monitoreo1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letrero_nivel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forget"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nivel 1"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letreroConductividad_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/botonverde"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Conductividad"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forget"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""

        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letreroPh_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/botonverde"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="PH"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valorPh_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forget"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Valor PH"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letreroTemperatura_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/botonverde"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Temperatura"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valorTemperatura_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/forget"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ValorTemperatura"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="490dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forget"
        android:text="Regresar"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la línea:

```
temp = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
```

`temp` no está definido por lo tanto es `null` y obtienes ese error. En segundo lugar, es simplemente `findViewById(...)`:

```
temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
```

Comment: Tienes razón !!! muchisimas gracias :DDD